# I have two phones same model, Google account sees older one but not newer one

Tags: google-account

I have two phones same model, Google account sees older one but not newer one

If I go to http://myaccount.google.com  then security then look under "your devices" so https://myaccount.google.com/device-activity    Then I see devices listed.

It lists my Moto G7 Power phone, the older one,  but doesn't list the other one  - the newer one.

And it lists, the older Moto G7 power, it just lists as Moto G7 Power. So if it did find the other one I don't know what it'd call it.

My older one(the one that is listed), runs Android 10.

My newer one(the one that isn't listed), runs Android 9.

(so yeah my older one has a later android than my newer one, and my older one is listed, while my newer one isn't.. so I don't think Android version is the issue).

I would like Google to see both devices!

**Update**

Now I see I was logged into a different account than the one I needed to be, on my laptop.. Google just sticks the letter "V" for my two google accounts.   Now the issue is slightly different and I have to dig more to figure out what that issue is.

Note- at a commenter's suggestion, I have included this comment in my question "I want it recognised partly for backup, partly for the 'find my device' option, and generally because I think google account should be linked to all my devices."

Comment: "*Now I see I was logged into a different account than the one I needed to be, on my laptop*", well, this might be a weird question, but make sure you're logging the phones with the same Google Account? I can see my 2 devices well on my main Google account.

Comment: @AndrewT. I did that though then I ran into a different problem that a google account that saw both phones could only make one of them ring.. anyhow now it seems to make them both ring.  One phone sent me to this link https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/3265955?visit_id=637619624900224879-1024371098&p=device_manager_location&rd=1  though I had all those settings on anyway. And suddenly the account was able to make both phones ring.